# How to generate Selenium HTML Report in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I created selenium test cases using TestNG. After that I created testng.xml and ran all classes parallely. Now the problem is to generate Selenium HTML Report in Jenkins. I exactly have to do that is mentioned in this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/seleniumhtmlreport+Plugin).
     For that how to generate Selenium Html Report. I used Maven as build tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium (RC) by itself doesn't generate any reports (as far as I know).  It relies on the testing framework that it gets coupled with.  Since you are using TestNG as your testing framework, TestNG does generate the html reports.  You can go to your test-output folder and check for index.html which would be a link to the results.  In case you are invoking through maven, check the target\surefire-reports folder for reports.

For integration with Jenkins, you can use the testng plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) which would give you the testng results on your job page.

You can also try if the html report generated by TestNG can be parsed by the plugin you mentioned, in case you want to use that plugin only.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried with that html files generated by testng... but selenium plugin in jenkins did not parse the files and it just open the html files

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Allure Report](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core) with pretty view and easy-to-use with maven

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://www.wakaleo.com/thucydides/ 
This library generates well reports, but needs some changes in code.